# Column visibility when multiple values vs single values are passed into a multi-value parameter - SSRS/Visual Studio

Tags: vba, reporting-services

Is there a way to make columns hidden/visible depending on whether a multi-value parameter is passing in a single value versus multiple values?

Currently my report is hiding Account Name and Account Number fields when searching by account. When searching by a boolean parameter, accountmaster, these columns are hidden with the following expression:

`=(Parameters!byaccountmaster.Value = 0)`

I would like to modify this argument so that the columns hide **only when a single value is passed** into the multi-value @account integer parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.Count` of the parameter.

```
=IIF(Parameters!byaccountmaster.Count = 1, True, False)
```

[image]

Comment: Flawless, thank you.